# Import javascript variable to checkout.php file for stripe integration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to import the js variable "total" to my checkout.php file so the total appears in the stripe "unit_amount"
this is my main.js file

```
// Update Total
function updatetotal() {
    var cartContent = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-content")[0];
    var cartBoxes = cartContent.getElementsByClassName("cart-box");
    var total = 0;
    if (cartBoxes.length == 0){
        document.getElementsByClassName('total-price')[0].innerHTML = "$0";
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < cartBoxes.length; i++) {
    var cartBox = cartBoxes [i];
    var priceElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName("cart-product-price")[0];
    /* var quantityElement = cartBox.getElementsByClassName ("cart-quantity")[0]; */
    var price = parseFloat (priceElement.innerText.replace("$", ""));
    /* var quantity = quantityElement.value; */
    total = total + price ;
    document.getElementsByClassName('total-price')[0].innerHTML = "$"+ total;
    }
    // Extract the total price from the HTML content
    console.log(total);
    $.ajax({
        url: "checkout.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { "total_price": total }
      })

}
```

`console.log(total)` works fine, and this is my checkout.php file

```
<?php
$totalPrice = $_POST['total_price'];
echo($totalPrice);
$totalPriceInCents = $totalPrice * 100; // Convert total price to cents
error_log("Received total price: $totalPrice");
error_log("Total price in cents: $totalPriceInCents");

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$stripe_secret_key = "";



\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe_secret_key);

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    "mode" => "payment",
    "success_url" => "http://localhost/php/AHMED2/projet-junior/test.php",
    "cancel_url" => "http://localhost/index.php",
    "line_items" => [
        [
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price_data" => [
                "currency" => "usd",
                "unit_amount" => $totalPriceInCents,
                "product_data" => [
                    "name" => "Total"
                ]
            ]
        ]
                
    ]
]);

http_response_code(303);
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
```

ps: i hid the secret key for privacy reasons.i also included the jQuery in my html file.

when i go through payement, the tripe page appears but with a total of $0.00, when i replace "unit_amount" with a value like 2000 it works fine.

Comment: It's probably worth noting for you and future readers that this allows the client to modify the price to any value they like.  Hopefully you have some kind of quality control after the purchase and before delivering any product...

Comment: Do please a `console.log` in a `.success` function.

Comment: what does the `echo($totalPrice);` and `error_log` prints ? when its the expected value then you have issue somewhere else then "transfering the value from js to php", most likely the `Stripe` itself. might not be the main issue but when you output something e.g. use the `echo` function, all headers are sent at that moment of first output, any modification of headers doesn't do anything, so use of `http_response_code` and `header` have no effect at all

Comment: Sounds to me, like you are making two separate requests to checkout.php here - one via AJAX, and then one by going to checkout.php _directly_ ...? (That rather _must_ be the case, because that redirect would _not_ take you to the stripe payment page in the first place, if the result of the AJAX call was not processed any further on the client side.) You would need to use a session, to be able to preserve the value across different requests.